# Predicate and expression to fetch complex request core data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have to make a complex core data fetch request but I don't know if it can be made.
This is my scenario: just one entity (Expense) with these attributes:

- **Cost** (NSDecimalNumber)
- **Deposit** (NSDecimalNumber)
- **Category** (NSString)
- **Paid** (Boolean Value)

The request should return the 3 most expensive categories but these are the rules that must be respected:

- If **Paid == YES**, Expense cost should be added to Expense category total
- If **Paid == NO && Deposit > 0**, Expense deposit should be added to Expense category total
- If **Paid == NO**, nothing should be added to Expense category total

Using NSExpression, I'm able to calculate every total per category but it also includes cost of Expenses not paid.
Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example, use a `NSFetchRequest`:

```
// Build the fetch request
NSString *entityName = NSStringFromClass([Expense class]);
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = entity;
```

which filters only relevant expenses:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(paid == YES) OR ((paid == NO) AND (deposit > 0))"];
request.predicate = predicate;
```

and sums up the cost and depost attributes:

```
NSExpressionDescription *(^makeExpressionDescription)(NSString *, NSString *) = ^(NSString *keyPath, NSString *name)
{
    // Create an expression for the key path.
    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:keyPath];

    // Create an expression to represent the function you want to apply
    NSExpression *totalExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction: @"sum:" arguments: @[keyPathExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

    // The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value
    expressionDescription.name = name;
    expressionDescription.expression = totalExpression;
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;

    return expressionDescription;
};

NSExpressionDescription *totalCostDescription = makeExpressionDescription(@"cost", @"totalCost");
NSExpressionDescription *totalDepositDescription = makeExpressionDescription(@"deposit", @"totalDeposit");

// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

request.propertiesToFetch = @[categoryDescription,
                              paidDescription,
                              totalCostDescription,
                              totalDepositDescription];
```

and group the results by category and paid status:

```
// Get 'category' and 'paid' attribute descriptions
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSDictionary *attributes = [entity attributesByName];
NSAttributeDescription *categoryDescription = attributes[@"category"];
NSAttributeDescription *paidDescription = attributes[@"paid"];

// Group by 'category' and 'paid' attributes
request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[categoryDescription, paidDescription];
```

You'll get paid and unpaid expenses summed up

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

all you need to do is combine (and sort) then:

```
if (results) {
    NSMutableDictionary *combined = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
        NSString *category = result[@"category"];

        BOOL paid = [result[@"paid"] boolValue];

        NSDecimalNumber *total = result[paid ? @"totalCost" : @"totalDeposit"];

        NSDecimalNumber *sum = combined[category];

        if (sum) {
            total = [total decimalNumberByAdding:sum];
        }

        combined[category] = total;
    }

    NSArray *sortedCategories = [combined keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    [sortedCategories enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Category %@: %@", obj, combined[obj]);
    }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: eik, thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and I saved my day! ;) It works like a charm!